# SharePoint 2013 Designer List workflow- How match two condition in if clause

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have created a document approval workflow and want to update another list column(Status) by matching the two value in if clause, I have give but it works independently not in combined way, like that in below image

[image: If clause with two condition]

what I have to do to satisfied these two condition together  not individually. please provide the apprpriate solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Vipin, Is document type is multi-select field like checkbox? If it is not how come document type will have two different values for single item?

Comment: No multiselect field, I have to set status in another list only when , document uploaded in library is of SIR and PPAP type.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are trying to achieve here. The Document Type field is of what type? Can we have multiple values or any of the one value. IF its any of the one value click on 'and' and select 'or'.